# How to update or uninstall new "All-In-One" QGIS macOS packages

Tags: qgis, macos

Recently new "All-In-One" QGIS packages for macOS have been released. This new packages make installation very simple but inside the .dmg file I have not found any readme file for uninstalling or updating: How can it be done correctly?